# Problems reading file from CloudStorage in Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read a file from CloudStorage in a deployed application, the code is very simple:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import logging
import os
import cloudstorage as gcs
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import app_identity


class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',
                                     app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Demo GCS Application running from Version: '
                            + os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID'] + '\n')
        self.response.write('Using bucket name: ' + bucket_name + '\n\n')
        gcs_file = gcs.open("/" + bucket_name + "/mylist.csv", mode="r")
        line = gcs_file.readline()
        self.response.write(line)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/view', Handler)])
```

But when I acccess the page I am getting a "500 Internal Server Error" and on the logs I can see the following:

```
10:24:32.791
suspended generator _make_token_async(rest_api.py:55) raised InternalError(5: )
10:24:32.792
suspended generator get_token_async(rest_api.py:224) raised InternalError(5: )
10:24:32.792
suspended generator urlfetch_async(rest_api.py:259) raised InternalError(5: )
10:24:32.792
Tasklet is <bound method _StorageApi.urlfetch_async of <cloudstorage.storage_api._StorageApi object at 0x10c98f90>>
10:24:32.792
Got exception "InternalError('5: ',)" from tasklet.
10:24:32.792
Retry in 0.1 seconds.
10:24:32.922
suspended generator _make_token_async(rest_api.py:55) raised InternalError(5: )
10:24:32.922
suspended generator get_token_async(rest_api.py:224) raised InternalError(5: )
10:24:32.923
suspended generator urlfetch_async(rest_api.py:259) raised InternalError(5: )
10:24:32.923
Got exception "InternalError('5: ',)" from tasklet.
```

The page loads fine if I remove the line where the file is opened.

Update: I believe the issue is related with the fact that the user {project-id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not exist in my app, and I am not able to add it back to my project, since the admin page only let me add users with the format {username}@{project-id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

So does anyone know how to add this user back to the project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem comes from the fact that the account {username}@{project-id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com was removed from the project and I am working on and the following thread says that there are no ways to recover the default service account once it has been deleted.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13085#makechanges